# Should I combine my Perl library and CGI program into one file for FastCGI?

Tags: perl, fastcgi

I am rewriting a CGI script to make use of fastcgi module. My initial program consists of two scripts. One "requires" the other. In terms of efficiency, do I need to rethink the whole "require" script and combine them both into one file? The scripts can be summarized as below:

Script A :

```
use FCGI;
# Do a lot of stuff and slurping (memory intensive)
sub use_my_slurped {
# Do sub here
}

sub use_my_slurped2 {
# Do sub here 
}

###############
# EOF A#
###############


Script B:
require A;

while (FCGI::accept >= 0) {
# main program functions
$blah = use_my_slurped (X,Y,Z)
print "Some HTML stuff $blah"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, A isn't a script but a perl library.

Second, FastCGI might handle this gracefully without modification.  It depends on if A is a fully qualified filename or not.

Third, will very little work A could become a module, and then everything should Just Work.

```
# A.pm
sub func1 {}
sub func2 {}

1;
```

And then

```
# B.cgi
use lib qw( /path/to/dir/containing/above );
use A;
# ...
my $blah = func1();
```

Comment: That still doesn't tell me which one or both should I use the fast cgi loop in. That is my main concern. If I do end up "use"ing A.pm, then would it load once and only once upon webserver startup ?

Comment: You mean sometimes A.pl jumps into B.pl and sometimes the reverse?  That's insane.  But given that, maybe you should have a C.pl, which loads both A.pm and B.pm and then handles FCGI for you.  C for Controler.  Then work at turning your spagetti into lazanga.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a problem leaving them as separate files. FastCGI doesn't need to load and compile the library for every request, so start up time is not that big of a deal as it is in normal CGI. Unless you're looking for things to work on, I'd probably just leave it alone.

However, if the library was written in some weird way where you need to load it once per request, that's a different story.

For your example, I think you need to move all of the FastCGI stuff into the same file. You load modules, such as FCGI, in the file that you want to use stuff from that module.